# FutureBuilder in flutter seems to fail fetching data, how come?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter

I have tried using FutureBuilder for a stateful widget,
I wrote a simple flask app and have checked the endpoint, it works well through the browser.
BUT in my **flutter app** I keep getting "no  Data" which means no fetch from the server was done.

How come the function getFamily() is not getting invoked (see below)?

I guess i'm missing here something basic :/ , i'd like to get the family.father!

below is my code in the stateful widget:

```
 Future<FamilyModel> familyFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    familyFuture = getFamily();
  }

  Future<AuditionModel> getFamily() async {
    print("Welcome to getFamily!!\n");

    final url = "http://192.168.1.2:5000/search";
    final response = await http.get(url);

    // for debugging only
    # print('statusCode: ${response.statusCode}');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      # print("You have reached here!!!");
      final jsonFamily = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return FamilyModel.fromJson(jsonFamily);
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

in the build part:

```
     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyCustomedAppBar(), // works well
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: familyFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('Active');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  final family = snapshot.data;
                  print("Done!!!");
                  return Text(family.father);
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text("none");
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Text("waiting");
                default:
                  return Text("default");
              }
            } else {
              return Text("No data");
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

The model is:

```
class FamilyModel {
  final String father;
  final String mother;
  final String sister;

  FamilyModel(
      {this.father,
      this.mother,
      this.sister});

  factory AuditionModel.fromJson(final json) {
    return FamilyModel(
        father: json["father"],
        mother: json["mother"],
        sister: json["sister"]);
  }
```

Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The future attribute for the FutureBuilder should be a function. In this case your future should be `getFamily()`. Please refer to the docs on FutureBuilder [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).